# WebAPI as Micro service in Cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cloud, microservices

Can we host the normal Asp.Net MVC WebApi built with c# code and **not in .net core** in Azure or AWS micro service platform?

Comment: Need the details on how to host the WebAPI as micro services built with C# and not with .net-core

Comment: Of course yes , infact many option to do that. Depends what you want to achieve ? Azure App service or AWS Elastic beanstalk are options to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean micro service. Microservices is mostly an architecture and not a specific platform. They are related to containers in a sense, but it's not the same thing.

Based on this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/microservice-applications/, related technologies include:

> Service Fabric
> Get automatic scaling, rolling upgrades, and self-healing from faults with a custom-built microservices framework.
>
> Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
> Use a fully managed Kubernetes service to handle provisioning, upgrading, and scaling cluster resources on demand.
>
> Azure Functions
>
> Build apps with simple, serverless functions that scale on demand based on the number of executions—without managing infrastructure.
>
> API Management
>
> Expose and publish specific parts of your applications as an API no matter where the implementation is hosted.

Kubernetes and ServiceFabric support containers which can be hosted on windows with iis, so the answer is yes.

The api management is agnostic and is used to expose, secure e.t.c your APIs.

You can even host .net web api on app service: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/dotnet/azure/dotnet-howto-migrate-app-service?view=azure-dotnet

In app service you can scale up and scale out.

Functions are serverless and they are not related to MVC api, they need new implementations.

Comment: Thank u for the data